# Swisscom Cloud Foundry: Is there a way to request app instances to run in separate regions?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

This is a question regarding the Swisscom CloudFoundry PaaS.

We use manifests to configure and provision our applications running in CloudFoundry. You can specify how many app instances you want to have running for an app there (or you can scale the app via `cf scale APP_NAME 2`).

What should I expect in terms of "regions" as to where these instances will be run?

- Is there any way for me to tell CloudFoundry to run instances in separate datacenters / regions?
- Will CloudFoundry itself try to start-up app instances in different locations?
- Will CloudFoundry most likely start them very close to each other?
- Is there simply no way of knowing / telling in which datacenter the App instances will run?

I would like to know what the recommended way is to run a CloudFoundry app on Swisscom's PaaS to maximise it's availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is no way to tell CloudFoundry app instances in which datacenter to run
- Yes, CloudFoundry distributes app instances across datacenters
- No, CloudFoundry is distributing it
- Yes, there is simply no way

Comment: Thanks - that's great info. Did you find any documentation / source for this?

Comment: I didn't check the source before, but it's also document here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/diego/diego-auction.html